# How can I define a derivation in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, programming, operators

I would like to define a derivation in Mathematica. As an example something like this: for an operator O and operators $A,B$ in a two dimensional vector space with
$$
O \times A = a \\
O \times B = b \\
$$
I would like that Mathematica can calculate for me

$$ O\times (A B) = (O \times A ) B + A (O \times B) = a B + A b $$

I am interested in having a whole finite dimensional ring $R$ of operators $A,B,C, \ldots$ and I need Mathematica to be able to understand that any operation of the form
$$
O \times Sym(R)
$$
is supposed to be a derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
o@(a_ ** b_) := o@a ** b + a ** o@b
o@(a_Plus) := o /@ a
```

With this,

```
o@(A ** B)                        (* A ** o[B] + o[A] ** B *)
% /. {o ** A -> a, o ** B -> b}   (* a ** B + A ** b *)
```

You can also use `TensorProduct` instead of `NonCommutativeMultiply` for a better looking output.

Comment: ... or you could just use `Dt`.